# Can i use Regexp in sqllite select

Tags: sqlite

In a SQLite query, I tried to replace some caracteres with this expression

```
SELECT Replace(var2,REGEXP '^\d',"AAA") AS var2 WHERE region = "toto"
```

But I had no success

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html#regexp) says:

> The REGEXP operator is a special syntax for the regexp() user function. No regexp() user function is defined by default and so use of the REGEXP operator will normally result in an error message. If an [application-defined SQL function](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/create_function.html) named "regexp" is added at run-time, then the "*X* REGEXP *Y*" operator will be implemented as a call to "regexp(*Y*,*X*)".

In any case, the built-in replace() does not support regular expressions.